# Intel RST RAID volume persists after disabling RST in firmware and after uninstalling RST driver?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces, intel-rst

*Edit: recap:
RST has been disabled in the firmware settings, RST driver has been uninstalled from Windows and the disks have been unpartitioned individually in Linux. Yet, Windows treats two disks as a single RAID 1 volume.*

Original question:

I have a motherboard that provided Intel RST RAID to the computer. Because the computer kept freezing a couple times a month for no good reason, I started taking out one thing at a time to figure out the cause.

After disabling RST in the motherboard settings, Windows still saw the RST RAID 1 volume. After removing the Intel RST driver from Windows, Windows **still** saw the RAID 1 volume. It is currently visible in Device Manager as "Intel Raid 1 Volume". When I boot the same computer to Fedora and look at the disks with GNOME Disk Utility, I can see two physical hard drives, both having a 17MB partition in the beginning, which Linux states is an Intel Enterprice RAID volume.

Is it that 17MB partition that allows Windows to keep using this RAID volume as a RAID volume, despite the fact that RST is disabled in the motherboard's firmware settings and the controller is in AHCI mode (*no, it is not; see edit*)? Is Windows actually treating the disks as a RAID volume? Is it Storage Spaces that does this (although it does not show the volume)? Or is Windows simply looking like it is treating the RAID volume as a RAID volume and, in reality, just using one of the disks?

UPDATE: Even after deleting the 17MB partitions on the disks and leaving nothing left, Windows still thinks they constitute a single RAID unit. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what was going on but reenabling RST in the firmware settings, reinstalling the Intel Rapid Storage Technology application and deleting the volume there made it disappear. Seems that disabling RST at firmware level did not disable RST in real life with a volume present.